# what does "const char(&a)[N]" mean?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was checking the C++11 features and see the following codes:

```
class conststr {
    const char* p;
    std::size_t sz;
public:
    template<std::size_t N>
    constexpr conststr(const char(&a)[N]): p(a), sz(N - 1) {}
};
```

I know `const char a[]`, but I am quite confused with `const char(&a)[N]`, anyone know how to use that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a reference to array of `const char` of size `N`. This is probably used to accept a string literal as argument.

```c++
conststr("whatever"); // ok
char const * psz_whatever("whatever");
conststr(psz_whatever); // error
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I didn't recognize at first glance. I wonder if "const char *a" has almost the same functionality as "const char(&a)[N]".

Comment: So in my case, it does not work if I use "constexpr conststr(const char *a): p(a), sz(N - 1) {}" instead. Is that right?

Comment: `const char *a` is almost the same but it will allow function to accept any pointers, including `nullptr`. Notice that `conststr` is a **template** function, so we get `N` deduced.

Comment: Using const char *a allows psz_whatever to be passed in the example above. const char[&a][N] forces a non-null string to be passed.